# Why my program executes before when it actually supposed to?

Tags: c++, execution

Okay here I have written a code, this program runs till the first while loop without executing the whole program. I have tied multiple ways like creating function, but facing the same problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1, str2, temp;
    string *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptrtemp;
    int i, j;
    cout << "Enter string A: ";
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout << "Enter string B: ";
    getline(cin, str2);

    ptr1 = &str1;
    ptr2 = &str2;
    //swaping
    ptrtemp = ptr1;
    ptr1 = ptr2;
    ptr2 = ptrtemp;

    cout << "Now String A is= ";
    i = 0;
    while (i < str2.size())
    {
        cout << *ptr1;
        ptr1++;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Now String B is= ";
    j = 0;
    while (j < str1.size())
    {
        cout << *ptr2;
        ptr2++;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you should learn to properly indent your code, so it's easier to understand the flow of execution. Then you should step through the code in a debugger so that you can follow it as it's being executed, which will most likely allow you to solve the problem yourself without our help. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: Debuggers are the bomb. Probably the only reason I had time to run Champions games in school was figuring out how to use Turbo Debugger early on.

Comment: After `ptr1++` `ptr1` does not point to a `string` object, then dereferencing `*ptr1` is undefined behavior - in your case the program crashes and terminates.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to use debugger, I will now diffidently learn to use it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please don't be diffident about learning to use debuggers! ;)    But you should definitely learn how to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptrtemp;
...
    ptr1++;
```

So, `ptr1` points to a string. You then increment its value, which makes it point to some other string. But there is no other string for it to point to.

I suspect you're thinking `ptr1++;` will somehow cause `ptr1` to point to a different character in the same string. But it can't possibly do that. A `string *` can only point to a string, it *cannot* point to a character in a string.

Comment: I thought that string works just like char arrays, that is why I was doing it the wrong way, now I have removed the loops, it is working as it is supposed to, Thanks for your help, I really appreciate that.